# How to compare a input value to value in results

Tags: testing, automation, postman

This is my input

```
{
  "AccountId": "9834e8cb-275a-4bff-b362-f216e9653686",
  "ContactId": "9834e8cb-275a-4bff-b362-f216e9653686",
  "AuthenticationDetails": {
    "AuthenticationId": "{{clientId}}",
    "AuthenticationType": "Token"
  }
}
```

This is my output

```
{
    "orderedByContactId": "36b8e4da-94fd-4680-a2d3-6b128e4b2584",
    "orderedForContactId": "9834e8cb-275a-4bff-b362-f216e9653686"
}
```

I need to create a test (postman) to ensure that the output value ("orderedForContactId") matches the input value ("ContactId").  Can someone help me out?

Existing tests are in the following format:

```
pm.test("Response should contain orderedForContactId",function(){
    let jsonRespData = pm.response.json();

    pm.expect(jsonRespData).to.have.property('orderedForContactId');
});
```

Comment: what error you get when executed the existing test?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, I'm just not sure how to make sure in the test that the input value matches the output value. (The test example I included in the questions is working and returning a positive test result).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a test where "Input- ContactId{value}" = "Output-orderedForContactId{value}", but don't know how to get the values to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your test script

```
pm.test("Response should contain orderedForContactId",function(){
   var requestJson= JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
   var contactId = requestJson.ContactId.toString();
   var responseJson = pm.response.json();
   var orderedForContactId = responseJson.orderedForContactId;
   pm.expect(orderedForContactId ).to.equal(contactId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the input to be

```
{
  "AccountId": "9834e8cb-275a-4bff-b362-f216e9653686",
  "ContactId": "{{ContactId}}",
  "AuthenticationDetails": {
    "AuthenticationId": "{{clientId}}",
    "AuthenticationType": "Token"
  }
}
```

And added the ContactId to the environment file.
Then I created the test below:

```
pm.test("Input ContactId should equal orderedForContactId",function(){
    let jsonRespData = pm.response.json().orderedForContactId;
    pm.expect(jsonRespData).to.equal(pm.environment.get("ContactId"))
});
```